# Running JSLint from command prompt

Tags: javascript, rhino, jslint

I would like to run jsLint from the command prompt.
At a later stage, as a task in an ANT build.

I downloaded rhino 1.7 R3 and the latest `jslint.js` and wrote this custom `test.js` which contents is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)  { }
```

Notice that this single line of code should already cause jslint to warn:

```
Move 'var' declarations to the top of the function.
```

I used this command:

```
java -jar .\rhino1_7R3\js.jar .\douglascrockford-JSLint-e31fa4c\jslint.js .\test.js
```

Which ran for a couple of seconds and then finished without any output.

My question  is -> Am I doing it right? What kind of output should I expect in case of an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Rhino etc, but when using JSLint in pure JS, it creates a `JSLINT` object, and you need to iterate through `JSLINT.errors` (which has methods `JSLINT.errors[i].line`, `JSLINT.errors[i].reason`, etc). Also, you have to pass your code as a string into the `JSLINT` function, not just run them both together.

Comment: See also the description https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js, you need to call e.g. `var myResult = JSLINT('for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)  { }', option); `.

Answer (score 3):

You might find [jslint4java](http://Code.google.com/p/jslint4java) useful as it has a command line interface, wrapping JSLint.